# Does Thomas the Tank Engine have free will?

Tags: thomas-the-tank-engine

In the story Thomas Comes to Breakfast, from Branch Line Engines by the Rev. W Awdry, Thomas's driver tells him:

> "You know just where to stop, Thomas! You could almost manage without me!"

Thomas, conceited, thinks this is literally true and that he does not need his driver anymore. So he decides to surprise the other engines by coming out of his shed by himself.

However according to the narrator:

> Thomas thought he was being clever, but really he was only moving because a careless cleaner had meddled with his controls.

He is unable to stop, and crashes through the the buffers in a siding and into the stationmaster's house.

It seems that Thomas thinks that at least some of the actions he can take as a steam locomotive are caused directly by his own volition, but in fact they are caused by outside forces that he is unaware of. It appears that he is mistaken about, or at least overestimates, the degree of free will that he thinks he has.

However the Fat Controller and other railway staff certainly do treat him as if he is capable of forming intentions of his own, since they hold him morally accountable: "You're a very naughty engine, you will stay in the shed until you are wanted" etc.

Does Thomas the Tank Engine in fact have free will or not?

By free will, I mean the ability to form intentions which cause events to happen in the world, which would not otherwise happen.

Comment: I realise that Thomas the Tank Engine may stretch the definition of fantasy, but IMO talking anthropomorphic engines are clearly fantastic constructs. Feel free to close if it is really off-topic.

Comment: Thomas can think, so he clearly has free will even if he cannot move of his own accord, in much the same way as a completely paralyzed person who is conscious certainly has free will. Thought is an event that occurs in the world. What he may lack is *autonomy*.

Comment: I think this would fall under the same category as "anthropomorphic animals" or other talking machine movies/shows like Cars or Bob The Builder and be off-topic. The trains are not seen as fantastical in-universe.

Comment: @Skooba - Indeed. There doesn't seem to be a fantasy or scifi element to their existece. It seems to be a perfectly normal part of life there; https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5117/are-anthropomorphic-animals-by-themselves-enough-to-deem-a-work-fantasy

Comment: @Skooba - Although there are magical *elements* in one of the later films;  https://ttte.fandom.com/wiki/The_Magic_Railroad

Comment: Would you consider asking this question on [literature.se] instead? I would've migrated it to that site if I'd seen it before, but now the post is too old to be migrated. Questions about the Rev. W. Awdry stories would definitely be on-topic there, although not fantasy enough to be on-topic here, and this looks like an interesting one!

Comment: Migrated the question to https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/18932/does-thomas-the-tank-engine-have-free-will